# jenkins pipeline virtualenv plugin withPythonEnv

Tags: python, jenkins, virtualenv, pyenv

On my custom jenkins pipeline, (pipeline virtualenv plugin installed before) I tried such code:

```
withPythonEnv('python3.5') {
     pysh 'pytest --cucumberjson=result.json testscript.py'
}
```

But it still looks as targeting Python2.7 platform in console output of pipeline:

> pytest --cucumberjson=result.json testscript.py
>
> ============== test session starts ================
>
> platform linux2 -- **Python 2.7.13**, pytest-3.6.3, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.6.0

On the other hand I run same py.test inside pycharm with venv of Python3.5 :

> platform linux -- **Python 3.5.3**, pytest-3.6.2, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: Hello, I am the creator of the pyenv-pipeline-plugin. I recently released a new version, and was hoping you would try it out to see if it fixes your problem. Otherwise, please open an issue in the Github project: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pyenv-pipeline-plugin

Comment: @BenKalender I think I still have same issue. ANy update from You?

Answer (score 1):

This threw me for a while as well.  It seems like the pyenv pipeline plugin doesn't understand pyenv aliases/names, but it can understand an environment's path.  In your case, if hypothetically your env was installed at `/root/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/envs/myenv_3_5_3`, this should work:

```
withPythonEnv('/root/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/envs/myenv_3_5_3/bin/python') {
   pysh 'pytest --cucumberjson=result.json testscript.py'
}
```